# React: getInitialState

Tags: reactjs

I wrote this function as getInitialState

```
getInitialState: function() {
        axios.get("****url ******").then(res => {
            myVariable = res.data;
        });
        return {secondsElapsed: 0};
    },
```

As you can see there is a promise in this function, and the code may reach to 'return' statement before the code inside 'then' is committed. However, when I run this code, I find out that it always reach the 'render' function after the code inside the 'then' has been committed.

DO you know how it possible? How can I guarantee for 100% that when reaching the render function, the code inside 'then' will have already been committed?

Comment: It's not a good practise to do an ajax call inside the getInitialState. You should do an ajax call iniside `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: I understand that componentDidMount is committed **after** render function. I need the AJAX results to render the page.

Comment: You need to have a `loader` variable which will show the loading state while your ajax request fetches the data.

Comment: `getInitialState` is to define the initial values of your variable. The data can be fetched later on.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a promise with axios there. A promise is asynchronous - meaning, regardless what will happen with the call (whether it will be successful and its callback function then() invoked or fails) the flow of execution of your code will not be affected.

To achieve your goal you need to set a state when your AJAX call is successful. in the then() callback. You can then, depending on the state value you set, render accordingly.

I would like to bring to your attention that your code does not follow react patterns. I recommend you to move your API call outside your main component and place it into an action. Then import the action in your main component and invoke it in getInitialState function.